# How to write cronjobs in seperate file nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I want to write a cron job on **node.js** which runs every minute. The tutorials that I viewed online all showed the cron job being written in the "App.js" or "server.js" file which is the main file on nodejs.

I want to seperate this into another file for better readability but I cannot find any solution or example online. please help.

I want to write this in a separate file just like we write our routes.

```
const cron = require("node-cron");

cron.schedule("* * * * *", function() {
    console.log("running a task every minute");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes. you can write your cron-job in separte file. when starting the server, you can invoke your cron job, like in your `app.js` or `server.js`. you just export your cron job file & impore here

```
import cronJob from "../filename.js"        
server.listen(3000, () => {
   cronJob.start();
});
```

Comment: Wroked Like a charm!

Comment: Yes. you better to use `cron`npm . you can also achieve in  `cron` npm

Comment: i will try that out as well

Comment: @krbalaji Is it initiate cron eveytime? like i deploy source on production and it has initialise crons and next deployment it start crons again. So it shouldn’t be run cron two times only once it should be run.

Comment: @JitendraSolanki Basically `node-cron` initialise along with the application.. So cron job should be initialise everytime if u restart/redeploy the application. it wont affect the scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 6):

You can create and export javascript modules elsewhere in your express/node.js app like this:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

require('./tasks/tasks')();

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

**tasks.js**

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

module.exports = () => {  
    cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
        console.log('running a task every minute');
    });
}
```

**Terminal:**

```
[nodemon] starting `node start app.js`
App listening at http://localhost:5000
running a task every minute
```

**File Structure:**

```
/tasks
    tasks.js
app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

`node-cron` *emulates*, rather than uses, the UNIX / Linux / FreeBSD [cron](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) subsystem driven by [crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) file entries. `node-cron` projects the illusion that functions in a running nodejs instance can be scheduled as if they were executable programs.

If you want to schedule a different nodejs program as a cron job, don't use `node-cron`, use cron. Put an entry in the OS's crontab mentioning the nodejs program.